# How to access wildcards within a run directive

Tags: snakemake

I'm using a `run` directive for a rule and would like to access a wildcard called `ref`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's just: `wildcards.ref`

Comment: I'm certain I tried this but failed for some reason. However, the minimal working example I provided in answer to my question shows you're right!

Answer (score 0):

A `Snakefile` with the following rule demonstrates the answer provided by @maarten-vd-sande is correct:

```
rule a:
        output: "{prefix}/{ref}/file.out"
        run:
                with open(output[0], "w") as out:
                        out.write(wildcards.ref)
```

Calling it like so:

```
snakemake prefix/reference/file.out
```

Results in a file with the following text:

```
reference
```